# Pass login information with each WCF Webservice call?

Tags: wcf, web-services, authentication

**Hi,**

I have set a WCF up as a webservice(percall), this webservice will getting request from a wide range of systems. Now we need somekind of way to identify the client.

Its possible to build a CustomUserNamePasswordValidation but this demands a secured(SLL) communication. In our case we do not need the security and the solution needs to be as easy as possible to setup.

So the question is how to send client identifikation(username/password) on each call?

I could place the identifikation data in the [header](http://geekswithblogs.net/JanS/archive/2008/03/17/automate-passing-valuable-information-in-wcf-headers.aspx) but Im not sure how this can be tested with example [soupUI](http://www.soapui.org/)? And Im not sure if all systems that will be communicate can handle this without complications?

**Any sugestions?**

*Please note: I do only want to do 1 call, so no login service method should have to be used.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF do not suport sending user credentials unsecured. To solve this you could use [the clear username binding](http://code.google.com/p/wcf-clear-username-binding/) or adding the credentials manually in the heador of the message(this is simple with WCF)

Answer (score 0):

Define a binding in the web.config like :

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicAuthBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Then define a service behaviour like :

```
<behavior name="Namespace.TestBehaviour">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Namespace.ServiceSecurity.UserAuthenticator, Namespace" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization>
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="Namespace.ServiceSecurity.MyAuthorizationPolicy, Namespace" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
```

Then provide the custom authentication and authorization classes as follows :

```
public class MyAuthorizationPolicy: IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        IList<IIdentity> identities = (IList<IIdentity>) evaluationContext.Properties["Identities"];

        foreach (IIdentity identity in identities)
        {
            if (identity.IsAuthenticated &&
                identity.AuthenticationType == "UserAuthenticator")
            {
                evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = identity.Name;
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (!evaluationContext.Properties.ContainsKey("Principal"))
        {
            evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = "";
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ClaimSet Issuer
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

authentication as follows :

```
public class UserAuthenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        //authenticate me however you want
        //then set whatever you want
    }
}
```

If you need further security, change basicHttpBinding to a wsHttpBinding and use a certificate

EDIT : Almost forgot, use the defined service behaviour and binding in your service interface definition in web.config.

Comment: > Thanks! I have now implemented this but gets the following exception when browsing the service : BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials.

Comment: > I have tried to set the binding to this : <binding name="BasicAuthIntegration">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
       </security></binding>, this is will get the service going but when try to call the service from a testclient(with ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and ClientCredentials.UserName.Password) I will get this exception(in client) : The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="localhost"'.

Answer (score 0):

In the code :

```
public class WCF_Project_Authentification : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    #region UserNamePasswordValidator Interface Member

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName != "Jeanc" || password != "fortin")
        {
            throw new FaultException("Authentification failed");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In the config :

```
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service_Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <serviceCredentials>

            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService.Authentification.WCF_Project_Authentification, WcfService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

And in the client code :

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Jeanc";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "fortin";
```

Comment: @Jean-Chritophe > Thanks, but I do already know how to use the UserNamePasswordValidator, the problem is that I need to pass client identification wihout any security.